# Variable / optional airity function in Haskell though "argument object" introspection?

Tags: javascript, haskell, arguments

Imagine you have a function `addTogether` that can take any number of parameters, and adds them all after the last parameter. I know this could be done ridiculously easily with a List, but I'm just trying out a concept here. I think I remember being able to do so in JavaScript by accessing the `arguments` object ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338291/javascript-infinite-parameters-for-function)). Would it be possible to implement an argument object monad in haskell that translates the arguments applied to a native function (syntactically, so you don't have to explicitly use `>>=`) into a list of arguments?

Comment: Well, because the type `a -> b -> c` means `a -> (b -> c)`, a function in Haskell actually only ever takes _one_ argument. (So for example, `f :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e` is `f :: a -> (b -> (c -> (d -> e)))`, and is a function that takes an `a` and returns (a function that takes a `b` and returns (a function that takes a `c` and returns (a function that takes a `d` and returns an `e`))).)

Comment: But what about a function that has it's type signature evaluated at run-time?

Comment: All the types are determined at compile time.

Comment: FYI, `printf` [does this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828072/how-does-haskell-printf-work), though not in the same way you're suggesting.

Comment: @AndrewC What about the number of arguments in a type signature? Isn't it critically explicit and limited?
 Oh wait! I forgot that you can have a list of functions aswell! Or... can you? Or can you only have partially applied functions?

Comment: Your question is very vague, please try to add some pseudo code that can help people to understand what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/03/01/how-haskell-printf-works/ - a good link "Polyvariadic Functions and Printf"